# How to customize shortcut in compressed file to run exe from current directory?

Tags: batch-file, shortcut, compression

How to customize shortcut in compressed file to run exe from current directory? For example, i want to put compress two file inside winrar first is program.exe and the second is shortcut to that program, if i compress that in rar extension, and copy compressed file in other directory and open with winrar and run shortcut, i get nothing. So my question is what code to put in shortcut to run program.exe regardless in which directory will be compressed file extract?

Answer (score 1):

You get nothing because there is no program to run. A compressed file isn't a filestore from which files can be run. When you "run" a file from a compressed file, the OS is actually extracting that file to a temp folder and then running it. When you tru and run the shortcut, its being extracted, but the temp folder in which it was extracted doesn't contain the actual .exe you're trying to launch, so nothing happens.

As to how you achieve what you want, I have no idea, but would not be suprised if it was not possible. If you're running the exe from a compressed file, why do you need the shortcut? Why not just click the .exe?

Comment: If you're running the exe from a compressed file, why do you need the shortcut? In case that have more than exe file and after first execution to run other, etc, main point is to find out how to know what is directory in which is shortcut...

Comment: Your point is not clear. How does having a single shortcut file relate to running multiple `.exe` files? Anyway, why don't you just rely on the information about what directory the `exe` is run from (instead of what directory the shortcut file is in)?